# Passing a variable from Jquery to PHP ($_POST)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, post

i´m doing a website for managing a school centre and i have a doubt i wish you can to solve it.

I have this code:

login.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1" />
</head>

<body>

<form action="comprobacionlogin_usuario.php" method="POST">
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre de usuario</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="usuario"  autocomplete="off" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <th>Contrase&ntilde;a</th>
     <td><input type="password" name="contrasena"  autocomplete="off" required></td>
     </tr>
  <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
</form>
¿No eres usuario? Pulsa <a href="altanuevoprofesor.php">aqu&iacute;</a>
</body>
</html>
```

nuevo_horario.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$curso=$_POST['curso'];
$clase=$_POST['clase'];
?>

<html lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="administrar_filas.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo_botones_tabla.css">
    Horario
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="elementos">
    <form id="datos" action="procesar_horario.php" method="post">
    <table border="1" id="tabla">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <td>Hora</td>
    <td>Lunes</td>
    <td>Martes</td>
    <td>Mi&eacute;rcoles</td>
    <td>Jueves</td>
    <td>Viernes</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr class="fila-base">
    <td><input type="text" name="hora_0" placeholder="Hora_0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="asignatura_lun_0" placeholder="Asignatura"><br><input type="text" name="id_usuario_lun_0"placeholder="Id_profesor"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="asignatura_mar_0" placeholder="Asignatura"><br><input type="text" name="id_usuario_mar_0"placeholder="Id_profesor"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="asignatura_mie_0" placeholder="Asignatura"><br><input type="text" name="id_usuario_mie_0"placeholder="Id_profesor"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="asignatura_jue_0" placeholder="Asignatura"><br><input type="text" name="id_usuario_jue_0"placeholder="Id_profesor"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="asignatura_vie_0" placeholder="Asignatura"><br><input type="text" name="id_usuario_vie_0"placeholder="Id_profesor"></td>
    <td class="eliminar">Eliminar</td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="curso" id="curso" value="<?php echo $curso ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="clase" id="clase" value="<?php echo $clase ?>">
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" id="agregar" value="Agregar fila" />
    <input type="submit" id="enviar"  value="Enviar">

    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        $conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "alonsosjumper", "alonsosjumper") or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
echo '<br>Conexi&oacuten satisfactoria<br>';

mysql_select_db("proyecto", $conexion) or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');

    $consulta= "select id_usuario, nombre, apellidos from usuarios where tipo_usuario='profesor' order by id_usuario";
    $resultado= mysql_query($consulta);

    echo ' <p>Lista de profesores</p>
    <table border="1" width="auto">
    <tr><td>Id_usuario</td><td>Nombre</td><td>Apellidos</td></tr>';

    while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{

    echo "<tr><td>".$fila['id_usuario']."</td><td>".$fila['nombre']."</td><td>".$fila['apellidos']."</td></tr>";
}

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

procesar_horario.php

```
<?php

session_start();

//I wanna have here the variable "cuentaInputs" to use it in the for.

$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "alonsosjumper", "alonsosjumper") or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
echo '<br>Conexi&oacuten satisfactoria<br>';

mysql_select_db("proyecto", $conexion) or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');

for($i=0; $i<$cuentaInputs; $i++) {
    for($j=1; $j<6; $j++)
{
    if($j==1)
    {
        $asignatura=$_POST["asignatura_lun_".$i];
        $id_usuario=$_POST["id_usuario_lun_".$i];
        $hora=$_POST["hora_".$i];
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO horarios (asignatura, curso, clase, fecha, hora, id_usuario) VALUES ('$asignatura', '$curso','$clase','lunes','$hora','$id_usuario')";

    echo $consulta;
    }
    if($j==2)
    {
        $asignatura=$_POST["asignatura_mar_".$i];
        $id_usuario=$_POST["id_usuario_mar_".$i];
        $hora=$_POST["hora_".$i];
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO horarios (asignatura, curso, clase, fecha, hora, id_usuario) VALUES ('$asignatura', '$curso','$clase','lunes','$hora','$id_usuario')";

    echo $consulta;
    }
    if($j==3)
    {
        $asignatura=$_POST["asignatura_mie_".$i];
        $id_usuario=$_POST["id_usuario_mie_".$i];
        $hora=$_POST["hora_".$i];
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO horarios (asignatura, curso, clase, fecha, hora, id_usuario) VALUES ('$asignatura', '$curso','$clase','lunes','$hora','$id_usuario')";

    echo $consulta;
    }
    if($j==4)
    {
        $asignatura=$_POST["asignatura_jue_".$i];
        $id_usuario=$_POST["id_usuario_jue_".$i];
        $hora=$_POST["hora_".$i];
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO horarios (asignatura, curso, clase, fecha, hora, id_usuario) VALUES ('$asignatura', '$curso','$clase','lunes','$hora','$id_usuario')";

    echo $consulta;
    }
    if($j==5)
    {
        $asignatura=$_POST["asignatura_vie_".$i];
        $id_usuario=$_POST["id_usuario_vie_".$i];
        $hora=$_POST["hora_".$i];
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO horarios (asignatura, curso, clase, fecha, hora, id_usuario) VALUES ('$asignatura', '$curso','$clase','lunes','$hora','$id_usuario')";

    echo $consulta;
    }
    }


    }
$resultado = mysql_query($consulta);

mysql_close($conexion);


?>
```

administrar_filas.js

```
$(function(){
    var cuentaInputs = ($(".fila-base").length);

    $("#agregar").on('click', function(){
        $('#tabla > tbody:last').after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="hora'+cuentaInputs+'" placeholder="Hora"></td><td><input type="text" name="asignatura_lun_'+cuentaInputs+'" placeholder="Asignatura"><br><input type="text" name="id_usuario_lun_'+cuentaInputs+'"placeholder="Profesor"></td><td><input type="text" name="asignatura_mar_'+cuentaInputs+'" placeholder="Asignatura"><br><input type="text" name="id_usuario_mar_'+cuentaInputs+'"placeholder="Profesor"></td><td><input type="text" name="asignatura_mie_'+cuentaInputs+'" placeholder="Asignatura"><br><input type="text" name="id_usuario_mie_'+cuentaInputs+'"placeholder="Profesor"></td><td><input type="text" name="asignatura_jue_'+cuentaInputs+'" placeholder="Asignatura"><br><input type="text" name="id_usuario_jue_'+cuentaInputs+'"placeholder="Profesor"></td><td><input type="text" name="asignatura_vie_'+cuentaInputs+'" placeholder="Asignatura"><br><input type="text" name="id_usuario_vie_'+cuentaInputs+'"placeholder="Profesor"></td><td class="eliminar">Eliminar</td></tr>');
        cuentaInputs++;

    });

    // Evento que selecciona la fila y la elimina 
    $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
        if (cuentaInputs>1)
        {
        var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
        $(parent).remove();
        cuentaInputs--;

        }
        else
            alert("No se puede eliminar la ultima fila");
    }); 

});
```

I would like to have the variable "cuentaInputs" in "procesar_horario.php" to use it in for. I need it for a dynamic timetable i´m doing which it´s possible to add or remove rows.

How I can to pass the variable cuentaInputs from Jquery to PHP?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you limit your code to only the parts that are significant to the problem? Nobody wants to examine such a piece of HTML and javascript.

Comment: plus. i wasnt even able to find cuentaInputs anywhere in your javascript/html code. is the variable name different?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the code of Javascript. It´s posted now.

Comment: I would just use a hidden form element like you are doing for other things and make it with the jquery before the form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reading your comment. it seems you are trying to send a rows of data. insted of putting for element name and id like the following

```
name="asignatura_lun_'+cuentaInputs+'"
```

use array indexing

```
name="asignatura_lun['+cuentaInputs+']"
```

this way you'll get following arrays in php

```
$_POST['hora']
$_POST['asignatura_lun']
$_POST['id_usuario_lun']   
//likewise for mar, mie, jue and vie
```

at the php side loop for hora array using foreach

```
foreach($_POST['hora'] as $key => $value)  //use $key for referencing other arrays.
{
  for($j=1; $j<6; $j++)
  {
    if($j==1)
    {
        //use $key for referencing other arrays.
        $asignatura=$_POST["asignatura_lun"][$key];
        $id_usuario=$_POST["id_usuario_lun"][$key];
        $hora=$value;   //$value is current horra
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO horarios (asignatura, curso, clase, fecha, hora, id_usuario) VALUES ('$asignatura', '$curso','$clase','lunes','$hora','$id_usuario')";

        echo $consulta;
    }

    //same for other weekdays
  }
}
```

**Reference**:
Read this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18723457/656539).

---

Before Edit :

I really cant understand most of your code. Please try to use english identifiers. but on a brief look, using a hidden input element should solve your problem. add this in your form which submits to procesar_horario.php

```
<input type='hidden' name='cuentaInputs' id='cuentaInputs'/>
```

you can update its value whenever you update cuentaInputs.

```
$('#cuentaInputs').val(cuentaInputs);
```

Comment: Although a more appropriate way will be to have a method submit the form and let that method prepare the values which needs to be sent to the server. check http://api.jquery.com/submit . If you need help with that. please modify and minimise your code a bit considering english only folks.

Comment: It doesn´t work. I explain to you. I need this variable to count the number of rows has the table created dynamically while Jquery. I want the "cuentaInputs" variable for using it in the "for" to insert data in MYSQL.

Comment: i have updated the answer. and please Do go through [Loenix's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19369424/656539) answer. Writing hora and profesor is good from user's point of view. But keep spanish or any other language only in UI. in the code/variable names, use english. It helps other english speakers working with you.

Comment: Yeah Mohit Jain, it works perfectly! 

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: you are most welcome. and welcome to SO as well. happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's ajax method will send some value to PHP like this.

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'procesar_horario.php',
  data: {q: putVariableHere}, //put a variable you want to pass here
  success: function (response) {
    console.log('yey, we passed the variable');
  }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();

//I wanna have here the variable "cuentaInputs" to use it in the for.
$cuentaInputs = $_POST['q'];
```

Comment: OP is trying to submit a form with that php script as form processor. sending it an ajax call wont help.

Comment: True, didn't read it well enough (not surprising I think) so I jumped to the conclusion prematurely.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot post the Javascript code. It´s correct now i´ve added the javascript code with your solution? Thankss

Comment: Is not there any solution then?

Comment: i have put an answer. check that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sign of jQuery in your question.
If you are developing an application, make sure to understand how it works or your project is doomed to failure.

jQuery is a library for Javascript, a client side programming language, that means this is the browser the user uses that is running the code (as HTML and CSS).
PHP is a programming language running on server side, that means clearly this is running on the server.
So you can not easily interact between them just with your own mind, there is no magic in it.

Browsers can natively submit a form with a submit button.
If you want do it with jQuery (or pure Javascript), you can trigger manually the submission (e.g with jQuery `$("form").submit()`).
You can also use it to send data to the server with AJAX features (e.g with jQuery `$.post({howifeelit:"good"})`) and the server gives you some results (HTTP inside).

Other advices:

- Prefer the international language for programming. (even if you love you mother tongue, i understand) This is more understandable and re-usable.
- Prefer PDO to old obsolete mysql_* functions.
- If you persist, please use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead of mysql_fetch_array(), this is lighter and you get what you want.
- Look at one of the million tutorial on the web to learn basics. (look at PDO, include, POST and framework keywords)